# ADD/REMOVE class based on div/section change with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed image and I need to animate it based on div/section  changes

```
<div class="fixed">
  <img src="some_image.jpg" class="child-fixed">
</div>

<section class="section" id="section-1">
//this is rotating section
</section>
<section class="section" id="section-2">
//this is flip section
</section>
```

and CSS something looks like this,

```
.fixed{
position:fixed;
margin:50% auto;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
.fixed-child{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.section{
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
}
.rotate{
//some css totate styles here
}
.flip{
//some css flip styles here
}
```

and JQuery Code will be like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
    $('.fixed-child').addClass( "rotate");
 }elseif($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
    $('.fixed-child').addClass( "flip");
  }
 });
});
```

Now I need to add rotate class when that image on section-1 and remove rotate class and add flip class when on section-2 with jquery,

I searched for that, I found some examples but using those examples I can add/remove class based on jquery scrollTop() method, but I want jquery detect that class and add corresponding classes when I scroll down and scroll up vice-versa.

I didn't write rotate and flip CSS code to reduce lines here. but those flip and rotate works.

Please help me to achieve this style!

Comment: So to clarify, you want to toggle 2 classes when a specific section comes into the viewport? Or when it dissapears? Or when it is in the middle? What have you tried? ScrollTop() sounds very much like what you need, or waypoints.js

Comment: yeah, i need to toggle  but there are 4-5 sections, when that image enters that section I need to toggle those classes, but device height changes according to screen size so I can't use scrollTop() **[maybe]**

Comment: So - this is a javascript / jQuery question - where's your javascript / jQuery code? What have you tried?

Comment: sory i forrgot to add, now i added that code

Comment: according to this script I can add the class based on top position, but I need to add/toggle class when that image div change the position of sections

Comment: What do you mean by "when that image on section-1"? If element with id "section-1" scrolls into view or shows at the top of viewport or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather from your question / comments you need something like [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)

> Waypoints is the easiest way to trigger a function when you scroll to
>   an element.

Comment: waypoint is also working as scrollTop() but I need something like [this](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/examples/layered-scrolling/)

Comment: there if section change the content also changing by adding and removing classes, they used scrollify library,

Comment: OK so both my answer, and the scrollTop() solutions solve the question being asked, the problem is that the question asked is not the question you want answering.

Comment: I suggest you look into the library you linked to and post back when you have a specific query regarding that plugin. Effectively at this point you are asking us to write the code for you, as you seem to know what library you want to use...

Answer (score 1):

I would also use waypoints for something like this, but as an alternative you can try doing something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var section_1 = $('#section-1'),
        section_2 = $('#section-2');

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll_lvl = $(document).scrollTop(),
          section_1_lvl = section_1.offset().top,
          section_2_lvl = section_2.offset().top;

      if(scroll_lvl >= section_1_lvl && scroll_lvl < section_2_lvl) {
           $('.fixed-child').addClass( "rotate");
           $('.fixed-child').removeClass( "flip");
      } else if (scroll_lvl > section_1_lvl && scroll_lvl >= section_2_lvl) {
           $('.fixed-child').addClass( "flip");
           $('.fixed-child').removeClass( "rotate");
      }


    });

});
```

Comment: Also notice in the html you posted in the question in the html the class name is "child-fixed" while in your css and js is instead "fixed-child".